# Looking for a way to communicate between multiple containerized spring boot apps behind nginx in a docker bridge network

Tags: spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have several spring boot apps that all have rest APIs, and they are containerized.  I am writing a `docker-compose` file to set up all of the containers to communicate with each other over a bridge network.  In the `.env` file, I list the ports that each app will use, and pass it in as `server.port` as part of the `entrypoint` arguments.  They are all on the same custom bridge network that I am calling `services_network`, and they all listen *only* on that network because their ports are available to each other (and not outside of the docker network) via `expose`.  I have nginx as a reverse proxy that provides an entrypoint on port 443 that forwards external requests to one of the services.  From there, I want that service to invoke other services, as necessary, and have all of the traffic stay inside of that docker network, until the original service returns a result back through nginx.

The services know about other services on the network through their `application.properties` where other services' URLs will be specified there.  But the configuration does not know what port is assigned to a service, because that is handled in `docker-compose` at "compose-up" time.  I realize that I could have each service go outside of the bridge network, and have any calls between services go through nginx.  But that is definitely what I do *not* want to do.  Is there any way that I can avoid specifying the port numbers in the URLs in the `application.properties` files, and still also avoid having the requests go outside and come back in through nginx?

Comment: Can you give a more concrete example of the setup you have now, and what parts of it aren't working?  Inside Docker each service has its own IP address; this is usually an implementation detail, but it does mean that every service can listen on the same port and there's no conflict (and if it's the default HTTP port 80 it doesn't need to be included in URLs).

Comment: @DavidMaze you actually answered my question quite well, even if I was not as specific with my question and explanation as you might prefer.  What you are saying makes perfect sense, now that you said it.  I did not understand that multiple containers can listen on the same port on the docker network.  It is just the external host network mapping that has to be unique.  But this makes sense and it simplifies my use case a lot!  If you post this explanation as an answer, I will accept it as *the* answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside Docker, each container has its own IP address.  Usually this is an implementation detail and you don't need to think about it much.  However, what this does mean is that each container also has its own separate set of TCP ports, and therefore that it's okay to have multiple containers listen on the same port inside their respective containers.

If you make calls between containers, these need to use whichever port the service in the destination container is listening on.  You don't specifically need to expose the port.  If you use `ports:` to publish a port to the host, this is ignored.  As with other HTTP URLs, if you are listening on the default HTTP port 80, you can omit it from your URL.

A typical Compose-based setup with an Nginx proxy, for example, might look like:

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
  # All external requests go through this Nginx proxy
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    # Make this service (only) be externally visible
    #   http://host-dns-name.example.com:12345
    #   https://host-dns-name.example.com:12346
    ports: ['12345:80', '12346:443']
    # The Nginx configuration includes
    #   proxy_pass http://backend
    volumes: [./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf]

  # Probably the main application
  backend:
    build: .
    # This is not externally visible; it does not have ports:
    environment:
      - PORT=80    # probably actually in the Dockerfile
      - PGHOST=db  # default PGPORT=5432, don't need to specify it

  # A normal boring PostgreSQL container; the primary data storage
  db:
    image: postgres:13
    # This is not externally visible; it does not have ports:
    volumes: [pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data]

volumes:
  pgdata:

# No top-level or per-service networks:; the Compose `default` network is fine
```